# Modify the auto-complete behavior in cell dropdown

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building a searching sheet, which take a dropdown cell as input data. User can select from the list, or type in the key word. Searched data will be populated by rows/column with my query formula. The search result itself works just fine.

However, the drop down list doesn't.

Here's a picture of my search.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, autocomplete would only populate 6 items, while my search query produce much more, which is exactly what I need. It's clear enough : Autocomplete **compare the whole text, not word - by - word.**

Is there anyway to change this behavior ?

My sheet is for other people to look for a specific item. I cannot expect them to know what I have entered in my database and force them to search by those exact keywords.

Anything from script to formula is fine with me. I just need at least, a lead..

Comment: That's how data validation drop-downs work. If you want your own autocomplete handling, then you should use a sidebar for input - you can write your own html input box and code your own autocomplete behavior. Review Apps Script `HtmlService` and custom UI / add-on guides.